# Import addition function from F# to C#

Tags: c#, f#

I recently learned that you import functions from the [F# core library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/) to C# such as

```
using Microsoft.FSharp.Core
```

...

```
var max = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.Aggregate(int.MinValue, Operators.Max);
```

Is there an equivalent function available for addition? I can't seem to find one. It would be cool to be able to write

```
var sum = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.Aggregate(0, Operators.Add);
```

Comment: What keeps you from using a lambda expression? `var sum = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.Aggregate(0, (x,y) => x+y);`

Comment: If you need to import the F# Core library, just because you want to use the F# function wrapping the `+` operator, then I'd say that's a bit excessive. (Everything else in your code sample is standard .NET + LINQ.)

Comment: why would u do this?

Comment: I am well aware that you can create anonymous functions. But I find it more declarative if I can just pass a function. When writing (x, y) => x + y I need to give names to 'x' and 'y', and the person reading the code has to consider what those names mean.

When writing something like Aggregate(0, Add) it's instantly clear what's going on without the distraction of variables. I must admit though that the op_Addition was a bit more lengthy than I'd hoped for. I can write such a function myself, Util.Add, but it does kind of take away from the clarity of using a standard library.

Comment: I'm not sure the above makes the code generally clearer... you can certainly opt for point-free style. and elide the variables, by passing in (+) as the function, at least in fsharp.  (this is basically a `fold` but C#'s LINQ can sometimes be a poor abstraction). I assume you have some other similar functions, because otherwise you would just `.Sum` it? (Forgot if C# has this very basic extension function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an addition operator in `Operators`: [`Operators.( + )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.%5b-p-%5d%5b%5et1,%5et2,%5et3%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)

You can consume it from C# using this:

```
var sum = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.Aggregate(0, Operators.op_Addition<int, int, int>);
```

Comment: I hope I just never see this in production code. :D